# Показать/скрыть элемент по клику на чекбокс

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Здравствуйте! Помогите, есть такая задача:
Есть два вопроса, у каждого по три варианта ответа, нужно что бы при выборе какого-либо варианта ответа (клику по чекбоксу), показывался скрытый блок связанный с эти чекбоксом, если пользователь кликнет на другой вариант ответа, то предыдущий блок должен скрыться. 
Сейчас если кликнуть на второй чекбокс, то первый блок не скрывается и если убрать все чекбоксы, то почему то все скрытые блоки отображаются, хотя их не должно быть видно.

---

**Есть вот такой код** [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrpdrtfp/)

```
 $('input.ShowOrHide').click(function() {

    var checked = $("input.ShowOrHide:checked");

    if ( checked.length == 0 ) {
        $("div.ShowOrHide").show();
    } else {
        $("div.ShowOrHide").hide();
        checked.each(function() {
            $( 'div#' + $(this).val() ).show();
        });
    }
});
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам нужно подумать над структурой вопроса, сейчас она очень печальна.

Comment: При клике вы проверяете длину массива с выбранных чекбоксов, если массив пустой (в случаи когда вы убираете все чекбоксы), то показать все `div.ShowOrHide`, а если нет, то сначала все `div.ShowOrHide` скрыть, а после на основе выбранного чекбокса показать соответствующий `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в том, что вы зачем-то добавили `checked` для открытия нужного `div`. На открытие нужно ставить именно тот элемент на который нажали, а у вас стоит `input checkbox` и оно сначала убирает поля, а потом показывает `DIV` всех выбранных `checkbox`.

```js
$('input.ShowOrHide').click(function() {

  var checked = $("input.ShowOrHide:checked");

  if (checked.length == 0) {
    $("div.ShowOrHide").show();
  } else {
    $("div.ShowOrHide").hide();
    $('div#' + $(this).val()).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Вопрос один</p>
<input type="radio" class="ShowOrHide" value="myDivId1" name="one" />1 div
<input type="radio" class="ShowOrHide" value="myDivId2" name="one" />2 div
<input type="radio" class="ShowOrHide" value="myDivId3" name="one" />3 div
<p>Вопрос 2</p>
<input type="radio" class="ShowOrHide" value="myDivId4" name="two" />4 div
<input type="radio" class="ShowOrHide" value="myDivId5" name="two" />5 div
<input type="radio" class="ShowOrHide" value="myDivId6" name="two" />6 div
<hr />

<div id="myDivId1" class="ShowOrHide" style="display: none;">div #1 content</div>
<div id="myDivId2" class="ShowOrHide" style="display: none;">div #2 content</div>
<div id="myDivId3" class="ShowOrHide" style="display: none;">div #3 content</div>

<div id="myDivId4" class="ShowOrHide" style="display: none;">div #4 content</div>
<div id="myDivId5" class="ShowOrHide" style="display: none;">div #5 content</div>
<div id="myDivId6" class="ShowOrHide" style="display: none;">div #6 content</div>
```

К сожалению ваш вариант реализации имеет много недостатков.

Comment: Спасибо большое, @Yuri 
а как можно сделать так, что бы скрытый блок в первом вопросе не пропадал, когда пользователь выбирает какой нибудь вариант во втором вопросе, как здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/alcheez/u84brd23/

Comment: @Alex, как вариант: найти общего родителя: https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/u84brd23/1/

Comment: спасибо большое.
А когда Вы сказали, что такой вариант реализации имеет много недостатков, что именно вы имели в виду?

Comment: @Alex, пользователь может открыть все варианты ответов сразу

Comment: последний вопрос, а сложно сделать, что бы логика сохранилась, но вместо radio были чекбоксы?

Comment: @Alex, да. Можете просто изменить тип на checkbox. А если хотите выключать остальные при нажатии, то воспользуйтесь скриптом (`elem.checked = false`)

Comment: а что бы когда убираю галочку с последнего чекбокса, все скрытые блоки не появлялись снова?

Comment: @Alex, `$("div.ShowOrHide").show();` измените на `$("div.ShowOrHide").hide();`

Comment: @Alex, смотрите в ответе, где заменить

Comment: @Alex, примите мой ответ, как правильный, что бы люди знали, что вам помогло

Comment: да сейчас отмечу, у меня почему то не выходит с тем что бы убрать предыдущие чекбоксы, я вот так сделал
https://jsfiddle.net/alcheez/6fobp0eq/

Comment: @Alex, https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/6fobp0eq/1/

Comment: @Alex, а лучше так: https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/6fobp0eq/2/

Comment: почему то если оставляешь одну галочку в первом вопросе и ставишь галочку во втором, а потом убираешь во втором, то скрытый блок не пропадает, это из-за чего может происходить?

Comment: @Alex, всё, решено :) https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/6fobp0eq/3/

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное! Можете пожалуйста объяснить из за чего происходило так, что не убиралась галочка? Я не очень понял

Comment: @Alex, у вас переменная `checked` брала элементы не из этого же элемента, а из всех. Получается, что оно когда вы снимали галочку, то в первом она стоит и checked показывал, что есть активный checkbox

Comment: теперь понятно, спасибо Вам большое за помощь!